# Best way to handle multiple currencies in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, currency

I have an where users can create an account and then create an invoice.  More international users are using the app which means I need to allow them to set a currency from a dropdown and that's used on their invoices.  I'm using `number_to_currency` everywhere currently, but how do I use that if say the currency code for a user is `ES` using the relationship `current_user.currencies.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out

1. Install this gem https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n
2. From here always use this format now `number_to_currency(100,:locale=>'en-GB')` you can choose from the list of formats here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale